# Hibernate Exception -- ast Syntax Query Exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, native-sql

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE) FROM store_variant_option_value  
WHERE store_variant_id = '1461' GROUP BY store_variant_id
```

I want to run this query in java code but getting java

> dialect exception

Tried everything from **native sql** to **hibernate named query** and **findByquery**.

Comment: please show the proper code along with the stacktrace

Comment: String sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE) FROM store_variant_option_value " +
        "WHERE store_variant_id = ? GROUP BY store_variant_id ";
   this.generalTraits = getBaseDao().findByNativeSql(sql, 0,0, this.storeVariantId);

Comment: result = {org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException@18368}Method threw 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException' exception.
detailMessage = {java.lang.String@18540}"No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1"
cause = {org.hibernate.MappingException@18541}"org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1"
stackTrace = {java.lang.StackTraceElement[84]@18370}
suppressedExceptions = {java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@18542} size = 0

Comment: please show us the hibernate xml file